# How to modify a Plotly graph's layout using custom buttons

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to create two buttons on a plotly graph object using `updatemenus`. On the button click I want to add a new title (which I can do) and add a new y-axis title. Adding the new y-axis title is where I am having problems. I for some reason can change the title of the graph on a button click but not the y-axis title even though I am passing both parameters to `args` in the same way.

Below is a working example

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(10,2)), columns=list('AB'))
df['Date'] = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-10')

# create two traces
traceA = go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['A'])
traceB = go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['B'], visible=False)
data = [traceA, traceB]

# create a new layout for each trace
traceA_layout = dict(title='Plot A', yaxis_title='Plot A yaxis')
traceB_layout = dict(title='Plot B', yaxis_title='Plot B yaxis') # change the plot B title and axis

# create two buttons for each plot
updatemenus = list([dict(type="buttons", showactive=True, active=0,
                         buttons=list([dict(label='Plot A', method='update',
                                            args=[{'visible': [True, False]},
                                                  traceA_layout]), # add layout to args
                                       
                                       dict(label='Plot B', method='update',
                                            args=[{'visible': [False, True]},
                                                  traceB_layout]), # add layout to args
                                      ]),
                        )
                   ])

# default layout
layout = dict(title='Plot A', title_x=.5, xaxis_title='Date',
              yaxis_title='Plot A y-axis', hovermode="x unified", 
              updatemenus=updatemenus)

# plot
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='test')
# py.plot(fig, filename='test.html')
```

[image]

When I click on the "Plot B" button it changes the graph and title but not the y-axis title. Is there a way to change the y-axis title on a button click? Is it possible to update the y-axis title using buttons?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work if you define the two layout dictionaries directly in the arguments lists as shown below.

```py
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df['Date'] = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-10')

# create two traces
traceA = go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['A'])
traceB = go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['B'], visible=False)
data = [traceA, traceB]

# create two buttons for each plot
updatemenus = list([dict(
    type='buttons',
    showactive=True,
    active=0,
    buttons=list([
        dict(
            label='Plot A',
            method='update',
            args=[
                {'visible': [True, False]}, 
                {'title': 'Plot A', 'yaxis': {'title': 'Plot A yaxis'}}
            ]
        ),
        dict(
            label='Plot B',
            method='update',
            args=[
                {'visible': [False, True]}, 
                {'title': 'Plot B', 'yaxis': {'title': 'Plot B yaxis'}}
            ]
        ),
    ]),
)])

# default layout
layout = dict(
    title='Plot A',
    title_x=.5,
    xaxis_title='Date',
    yaxis_title='Plot A yaxis',
    hovermode='x unified',
    updatemenus=updatemenus
)

# plot
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='test')
```

Comment: Thank you. Interesting that it works that way and not the other.